# eth0 and eth2 MAC addresses switch randomly

Tags: mac

I am running 20.04 and notice that the MAC address switches between the 2 interfaces (designated as eth0 and eth1). Where eth0 is configured for DHCP and eth1 has a static IP address assigned. When rebooting the machine, the MAC address switches resulting in eth0 no longer able to receive an IP address. Has anyone else seen the issue where MAC addresses switches between interfaces? I would appreciate any help. Thanks.

Interfaces are currently configured as shown below:

Gateway:~$ cat /etc/network/interfaces.d/eth0
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
MACADDR=84:8b:cd:40:3c:c2
ONBOOT=yes
NM_CONTROLLED=no
Gateway:~$ cat /etc/network/interfaces.d/eth1
auto eth1
iface eth1 inet static
address 10.0.2.1
netmask 255.255.255.0
MACADDR=84:8b:cd:4c:da:48
ONBOOT=yes
NM_CONTROLLED=no
Gateway:~$

Comment: Perhaps you can edit your question and include how `eth0` and `eth1` are configured.  What does your configuration files look like?

Comment: It could be that these interfaces are not detected in the same order on every boot. An indication of this would be the outputs of `dmesg | grep eth` (when it has just booted), both when the MAC addresses are in the correct configuration and in the wrong configuration

Comment: Which type of hardware do provide these? It *might* be of relevance here.

Comment: Thank you all for your comments. I was not able to respond because of family issues and will have limited access to the internet.

Comment: Ray - Thank you for your comment. Configuration added to original question

Comment: Emre Talha - Thank you for your comment. Can you instruct me as to how I can delay one of the interfaces to allow the other interface to come up first?

Comment: Hannu - Thank you for your comment. The interfaces are two ethernet interfaces on a Single Board Computer.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be able to solve that by making an udev rule in /etc/udev/rules.d which tie the device name to the mac address.
I have done something like that in the past and it works fine. Check the following link for some directions:

http://fewstreet.com/2015/06/09/ubuntu-udev-naming-rules.html

or

http://weng-blog.com/2017/05/udev-rule/

or

https://villasyslog.net/udev-rules-for-network-interfaces/

a rule such as the following in file "/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules"

```
# Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL-8139/8139C/8139C+
 SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="b6:5d:09:9e:f0:dc", ATTR{type}=="1", NAME="eth0"
 # Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL-8139/8139C/8139C+
 SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="c2:77:a2:d8:fd:c8" ATTR{type}=="1", NAME="eth1"
```

after making the rule reboot or issue the command "udevadm control --reload-rules" or something along those lines

Comment: thanks storestyggeulv! (interesting handle). I will take a look at this today.